# Laravel relationship hasMany returns null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've a relationship between two tables : `chapters` and `modules` and here they are :

```
class Chapter extends Model
{
    public function module()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Module::class, 'module_id');
    }
}

class Module extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'slug';
    public function chapters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class, 'module_id');
    }
}
```

But when I use the relationship it always returns nothing :

```
$module->chapters;
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong columns:

```
public function chapters()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class, 'module_id');
}
```

The same goes for the `module` relationship:

```
public function module()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Module::class, 'module_id');
}
```